# Dynamically loading content into a div from either and external or internal div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Im currently creating a site which has a div like below:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="one-third column">
        <a id="tab1" href="inc/tab1.html"><h2>tab1</h2></a>
    </div>

    <div class="one-third column">
        <a id="tab2" href="inc/tab2.html"><h2>tab2</h2></a>
    </div>

    <div class="one-third column">
        <a id="tab3" href="inc/tab3.html"><h2>tab3</h2></a>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="container" style="margin:100px 0;">
    <div id="information">


    </div>

</div>
```

Then i would like the content from the external page (which is basically just a div with a little bit of content in it) to be loaded into the div with id="information"

I tried using this but it just sends me to an external page?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(#tab1).click(function() {
    $('#information').load("inc/tab1.html");

    return false;
});
    $(#tab2).click(function() {
    $('#information').load("inc/tab2.html");

    return false;
});
$(#tab3).click(function() {
    $('#information').load("inc/tab3.html");

    return false;
});
</script>
```

Also by doing it this way is the content that is currently in the div hidden once the new content is loaded?

Then i was wondering how to add animation to the loaded content?

Comment: What do you mean with *add animation to the loaded content*?

Comment: Does the information have to be stored on an external page? It's much easier just to hide something that's already on the page.

Comment: you may need to call e.preventDefault() in the callback functions instread of returning false; e is the argument of the callback functions

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
$(#tab2).click(function() {

    $('#information').load("inc/tab2.html");
    return false;

});
```

to

```
$("#tab2").click(function(e) {

    $('#information').load("inc/tab2.html");
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Notice the quotes around `tab2` (you need to have those unless it's body, document.
Also notice the `e` in `function(e)`. With that you can prevent a link from redirecting to another page with the code `e.preventDefault()` inside of that function.

Answer (score 0):

That's because there are several syntax errors in your code, you are missing quotes for the selectors.

```
$('#tab...').click(function() {
    // ...
});
```

You can also use the `href` properties instead of having several handlers:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.one-third a').click(function(e) {
       e.peventDefault();
       $('#information').load(this.href);
    });
})
```